# How can i select combine data of multiple table from the following sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Actually it is dynamic query and i want the data of the tables who has the 'Schema: Document' .

```
select  Id,Code,[Address]
from sys.tables
where name in (select '[Document].'+name as table_name
               from sys.tables
               where schema_name(schema_id) = 'Document')
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: You are selecting from `sys.tables` with a where clause that subqueries `sys.tables`. You can almost certainly accomplish this in a single query... Why not `SELECT Id, Code, [Address] FROM sys.tables WHERE schema_name(schema_id) = 'Document'` ?

Comment: @h0r53 I am getting errors on your solutions:

  SELECT  Id,Code,[Address] FROM sys.tables WHERE schema_name(schema_id) = 'Document'

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Invalid column name 'Id'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Invalid column name 'Code'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Invalid column name 'Address'.

Comment: Have you checked the schema of your `sys.tables` table? It appears to not have the columns you are looking for. In a few DBMS you can do this with `DESC sys.tables`, but since you did not provide your DBMS it isn't clear which command to use to see the columns of `sys.tables`.

Comment: @h0r53 I am using SQL server.  , i just added 'sys.tables' as only guess, just i want the data of certain column from table  that have schema 'Document'. There are multiple tables having schema 'Document' and i want all those data  of certain column , let say Id,Code,[Address]

Comment: I'm guessing you mean MS-SQL Server. Regardless, I think I know what you're asking. You want to first identify tables that have `schema_name` Document, then you want to `SELECT Id, Code, Address` from those tables. The short answer is, you can't do this, at least how you're attempting to. If you really need this, you'll need temp tables and cursors.

Comment: @h0r53 exactly that. do ypu have example for it please? I am using sql server. I was mentioning guess for another word.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you have some tables, each of which has

1. the schema as `Document`
2. the 3 fields `Id`,`Code`,`[Address]`

I'm using a cursor.
Also note that this doesn't cater to any table which doesn't have the relevant fields, but has the same Schema. Also assuming that you are OK with data as query results

```
Declare @SQLQuery varchar(max)
DECLARE @returnData TABLE (tblName varchar(100), Id int,Code varchar(100),[Address] varchar(100))
DECLARE csr_docTbl CURSOR

FOR select ' Select ''' + name + ''' as Tbl, Id,Code,[Address] from [Document].' + name as table_name
        from sys.tables
        where schema_name(schema_id) = 'Document'

OPEN csr_docTbl;
FETCH NEXT FROM csr_docTbl INTO @SQLQuery
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    Insert into @returnData(tblName, Id, Code, [Address])
    Exec (@SQLQuery) 
    FETCH NEXT FROM csr_docTbl INTO @SQLQuery
END;

CLOSE csr_docTbl;
DEALLOCATE csr_docTbl;

Select * from @returnData
```